# Bash if statement syntax error

Tags: bash

I'm at a loss as to why this is giving a syntax error.  Any thoughts?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ `date +%H` -lt 11 ] ; then exit 0;
fi

if [ `date +%H` -gt 14 ] ; then
  if[ `date +%H` -lt 20 ] ; then  # <--- this line is the culprit, it seems
    exit 0;
  fi
fi
```

When run, I get:

```
./get.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./get.sh: line 7: `  if[ `date +%H` -lt 20 ] ; then '
```

Comment: editor with syntax highlight can help you in similar situations. My gedit don't highlight second `if` in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that this is a syntax error is that `[` isn't part of the shell syntax; it's actually a command.  Originally it was just a symlink to the `test` command.  It still is, but it's also a built-in command in bash and other Bourne-derived shells.

`if` *is* a shell keyword, but the shell sees `if[`, not `if`.  Because it didn't see an `if`, it doesn't know what to do when it sees `then`.  (Actually, it knows exactly what to do: print a syntax error message.)

...

A bit of experimentation shows that it's not quite as simple as I thought it was.  I tried creating a command called `if[` and putting it in a directory in my `$PATH`.  When I type just `if[` at the prompt, the shell asks for more input.  I actually don't know what it's looking for, but apparently the `[` character is specially treated by the shell.  The shell just doesn't split `if[` into the `if` keyword and the `[` command (as you might reasonably expect based on how other languages work).  (If I really wanted to execute that command, I could type `\if[` or `"if["` -- or give it a sane name in the first place.

In any case, that last part probably doesn't matter; adding a space character will fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you!  The lack of space there didn't even register in my brain, let alone as a possible culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Add space before `[`

```
if [ `date +%H` -lt 20 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if[ `date +%H` -lt 20 ] ;
```

you need to place a space after `if`

```
if [ `date +%H` -lt 20 ] ;
```